Problem with laser_scan_matcher usage
I'm trying to use the laser_scan_matcher package with a robot that do not publish its odometry, neither has a laser scan sensor. I'm using the "depthimage_to_laserscan" package to get a 'fake scan' using its depth camera. Now, the 'laser_scan_matcher' package is being used in order to emulate the odometry, the next step would be running a SLAM package and do a map of an environment.
I'm facing a problem when running this package, and it says:
:err: Strange FOV: 0.147378 rad = 8.444151 deg 
[ WARN] [1717755316.154036063]: Error in scan matching
[ WARN] [1717755316.254448674]: Could not get base to fixed frame transform, "world" passed to lookupTransform argument fixed_frame does not exist. 

First of all, I don't understand the "Strange FOV" bit but that's not my main concern right now. My problem is that, under my understanding of the error, the package is looking for a transform between the fixed frame and the base frame?? Isn't that what the package is supposed to publish?? Here is my code for the package:
<launch>

  <!-- Inicialización del nodo -->
  <node name="laser_scan_matcher" pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    
    <remap from="scan" to="/scan"/>

    <param name="fixed_frame" value="world" />
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />

    <param name="use_imu" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_odom" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_vel" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_cloud_input" value="false"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_pose" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_pose_stamped" value="false"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find slam_go1)/config/laser_scan_matcher_config.yaml" command="load"/>
  
  </node>

</launch>


And my TF tree consists of two unconnected trees that look like this:
aux --> world /// (unconnected) /// base_link --> laser_frame
All the connections created are by static transformers, like this:
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser_frame" />
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="aux_to_world" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 aux world" />

I would expect that the package would "create" the connection between both trees, connecting them in a single tree, but it doesn't. Can someone help me? I feel like I'm missing something obvious about the usage of the package but I haven't seen anything wrong with my approach yet. Anything is appreciated.
